# What is triggered when "Done" is pressed after changing from "Edit" in UINavigationItem bar for UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationitem

Short: In Swift/iOS, when does the "Done" (which was previously "Edit") nav bar button trigger when getting out of the UITableViewController "Edit" mode? When the user presses "Done" I'd like to enable a "+" button in my UINavigationItem bar so the user can once-again add rows by migrating to another view controller.

Longer: When a UITableViewController is showing below a UINavigationItem nav bar, there is an "Edit" button which turns into "Done" after it's clicked to enable deletes & move/drags.  Works great when this button is enabled via uncommenting code in viewDidLoad() generated as part of the UITableViewController class:

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

I've got my move/drags & deletes working fine, but  I want to appropriately disable my "+" button (addBarButton, used for navigating to another view controller to add a new row) while the user is in the Edit mode.  I'd then like to re-enable addBarButton after the user has clicked "Done" (which turns back into "Edit").

It looks like disabling addBarButton during the func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) is correct.  If I read Apple's docs right, this is triggered when user presses Edit in the nav bar.  What I don't know is what is triggered when the user presses "Done" (the button formerly labeled "Edit"). If I enable my addBarButton "+" button after the func tableView with moveRowAt, this enables addBarButton before the user has pressed "Done".

The Apple doc I'm referencing is at:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH11-SW1

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is right in the description for the `UIViewController editButtonItem` documentation:

> If one of the custom views of the `navigationItem` property is set to the returned object, the associated navigation bar displays an Edit button if `isEditing` is false and a Done button if `isEditing` is true. The default button action invokes the `setEditing(_:animated:)` method.

The last sentence is the key. You should override the `setEditing(_:animated:)` method in your table view controller subclass. Be sure you call the `super` implementation and then perform whatever custom action you want based on whether the controller is entering or exiting editing mode.

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if (editing) {
        // User tapped the Edit button, do what you need
    } else {
        // User tapped the Done button, do what you need
    }
}
```